# checking for NULL in a select CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

When n.ownerid is null, it will never execute this part:

```
...........,case n.ownerid
    when NULL then 
    (
    select systemuserid
    from crm_systemuserbase 
    where firstname = 'CRM' and lastname='Admin' 
)...........
```

Here's more surrounding code:

```
,case n.ownerid
    when NULL then 
    (
    select systemuserid
    from crm_systemuserbase 
    where firstname = 'CRM' and lastname='Admin'
    )
    when '6e99ff04-f498-e311-93f3-005056a37b31' then
    (
    select systemuserid
    from crm_systemuserbase 
    where firstname = 'CRM' and lastname='Admin'
    )
    end as OwnerID
```

**In a SELECT CASE how does one check whether the value of the field question is null?**

Answer (score 7):

Use the `is` operator when comparing to `null`

```
case when n.ownerid is null then ...
     when n.ownerid = '6e99ff04-f498-e311-93f3-005056a37b31' then ...
end as OwnerID
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that this means that you've had to switch from a simple `CASE` to a searched `CASE` expression

Answer (score 2):

you could also use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) expression:

```
CASE when COALESCE(n.ownerid, '(nullVal)') = '(nullVal)' . . .
```